# ¿Por qué no ejecuta la función Javascript el onclick de este checkbox?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, que por alguna razón no me ejecuta la funcion "comprobarRespuesta()" al clicar el input que tiene un onclick colocado que ejecutaría la función.

**Función:**

```
<script language="javascript">
      function comprobarRespuesta(respuestaUsuario){
        if(respuestaUsuario==<?php echo $_SESSION['respuestaLetra'];?>)
          alert("¡Correcto!")
        else
          alert("¡Incorrecto!") 
      }
</script>
```

**Que debería ser llamado al clicar en:**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="example1" onclick="comprobarRespuesta(a)">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"><?php echo $_SESSION['aRespuesta'];?></label>
</div>
```

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si que te estará ejecutando la fución, lo único que no sabe que es el parametro a que le pasas.

Es decir cuando llamas a la función `comprobarRespuesta(a)` no sabe interpretar que es esa `a`, porque al ir sin comillas interpreta que es una variable.

Para solucionar eso añade a lo que le pasas a la función unas comillas. `comprobarRespuesta('a')`.

Todo quedarías asi:

```js
function comprobarRespuesta(respuestaUsuario){
        if(respuestaUsuario=='a')
          alert("¡Correcto!")
        else
          alert("¡Incorrecto!") 
      }
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="example1" onclick="comprobarRespuesta('a')" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"><?php echo $_SESSION['aRespuesta'];?></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No funciona porque el parámetro `a` que pasas en la llamada no existe.

Si por ejemplo quieres pasar el `name` del `checkbox`, tienes que pasar el parámetro `this.name`.

```js
function comprobarRespuesta(respuestaUsuario) {
    console.log(respuestaUsuario);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="example1" onclick="comprobarRespuesta(this.name)" >
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"></label>
</div>
```

---

O, si quieres pasar una referencia al elemento completo, pasas `this`.

```js
function comprobarRespuesta(respuestaUsuario) {
    console.log(respuestaUsuario.name);
    console.log(respuestaUsuario.id);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="example1" onclick="comprobarRespuesta(this)" >
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"></label>
</div>
```

---

### Recomendación

De todos modos, no es recomendable poner las funciones de llamada en el código HTML ya que estarías escribiendo un código demasiado dependiente de cara a futuras evoluciones del mismo. Es decir, si hay que cambiar algo, tendrías que urgar en todos los archivos HTML buscando a ver donde están las funciones para hacer ese cambio. Los dos ejemplos anteriores son un claro ejemplo. Supongamos que en un principio le pasas sólo el `name` y luego te dicen que se requiere también el `id`, vas a tener que explorar todos los HTML para modificarlo.

En este ejemplo, liberamos a los checkbox de su atributo `onchange` en el HTML, y hacemos la escucha desde Javascript. Si hay que hacer cambios, no necesitamos editar el HTML, sólo lo hacemos a nivel de Javascript.

Además, esta función se puede asignar a elementos agrupados por `name`, por `class`, etc.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("customCheck1");
checkbox.addEventListener("change", comprobarRespuesta, false);

function comprobarRespuesta(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  console.log(el.name);
  console.log(el.id);
  console.log(el.checked);
  console.log(el.type);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"></label>
</div>
```